# MySQL Inserting a record for each already existing record

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys basically I have a query that select all the clientId where the flagId = 6

which is:

```
SELECT clientId from ClientsFlags WHERE flagId = 6;
```

Now I want to take the results from this query and create a new record for the each of the results obtained in the select statement

```
INSERT INTO clientFlags clientId, flagId VALUES('The client ID's that were obtained in the select query', 42);
```

What is the best way to combine these statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [INSERT ... SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO clientFlags (clientId, flagId) 
    SELECT clientId, 42 
    FROM ClientsFlags 
    WHERE flagId = 6;
```

Something like this, I haven't test it for syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO clientFlags (SELECT clientId,42 from ClientsFlags WHERE flagId = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Your query should look like,

```
INSERT INTO clientFlags (clientId, flagId) 
   SELECT clientId, flagId 
   FROM ClientsFlags WHERE flagId = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO clientFlags (clientId, flagId) SELECT clientId, 42 from ClientsFlags WHERE flagId = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do As Like Following

```
 INSERT INTO `clientFlags` 
 SELECT * FROM `clientFlags` WHERE `flagId` = 6
```

**Note:** Also you will have to be remember that any field could not be unique or primary key ...